# Why Harry Potter can't see the thestrals at the beginning?

Tags: harry-potter

In the *Harry Potter* series, why can't Harry see the thestrals the first time he encounters the carriages? He obviously saw his mother die when he was a child, but until he saw Cedric die, he could not see the thestrals.

Comment: Actually I don't know if he specifically saw his mother die; there's nothing I can think of in the books to indicate that he was specifically watching.

Comment: Yes, this is a dupe of at least two questions. I've chosen the one that's the more relevant.

Comment: I was reading something about this, JKR said that you have to see someone die and have complete understand about the event, on HP movies HP sees his mother die, but anyways, someone "have to know what death is, and have complete understand about it".