# Why couldn't Harry always see Thestrals? (since the age of one)

Tags: harry-potter

In both the books and films, it's made clear that Harry saw his mother dying when he was a baby. He clearly remembers this, due to the flashbacks that are induced every time he gets near a Dementor.

However, he only sees the Thestrals (creatures that require you to have seen death for them to appear visible to you) after Cedric Diggory dies.

Why is this?

Comment: Dupity dupe: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8182/why-couldnt-harry-see-thestrals-at-the-end-of-goblet-of-fire

Comment: In addition to the question @Jonah mentioned, this has already been [asked](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84949/why-harry-potter-cant-see-the-thestrals-at-the-beginning) twice [more](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73247/why-cant-harry-see-the-thestrals). Good question though!

Comment: @Randal'Thor I did see those two questions, but I feel like it's a seperate issue. However I do see that the Quote from Rowling " I said that you had to have seen the death and allowed it to sink in a little bit before slowly these creatures became solid in front of you, so that's how I am going to sneak past that one." explains it nicely, so thank you :)

Comment: You question is a separate question. Unfortunately, it falls afoul of the rule that if an *answer* to another question answers yours, that's enough for it to be duplicate.

Comment: Your question is different from the one @Jonah mentioned (although its answers solve this one), but seems identical to the two I linked to (which is why I mentioned them rather than just closing outright).

Comment: Apparently this is now *the* question that JKR is tired of justifying lol.

Comment: Do you think wizards try to use this as some sort of comfort? Mrs Weasley turns to the surviving twin, pats him on the back and says, "Look on the bright side. At least you'll be able to see Thestrals now."

Comment: @ThruGog JK said that George never got over the loss of his brother. So maybe not, considering you have to "process" the death